# How to disable use branch name with GitVersion

Tags: gitversion, build-numbers

Is there a way to disable GitVersion using the branch name?

We had an inadvertent build number increment as the result of using a branch named: 3.16-changelist

The current build version was 3.16.0

After merging that branch it was: 3.16.1

That was unexpected. Wondering if that behavior can be disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the version wasn't 3.16.1-changelist?
The version on your new branch should be larger than the one  on your master (3.16.0 < 3.16.1-changelist < 3.16.1 )
If you build deployment artifacts on all your branches you should probably make sure to handle releases and pre-releases differently in deployment.
One might prefer to only build deployment artifacts from master but your needs might be different.

Comment: can you add your version config, and output of the `gitversion /output buildserver /nofetch /nocache`